# Prove inequality $\sum _{cyc}\frac{2ab}{\sqrt{c+3}}\le 3$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, uvw

> For $a>0$, $b>0$, $c>0$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=3$ Prove that $$\frac{2ab}{\sqrt{c+3}}+\frac{2bc}{\sqrt{a+3}}+\frac{2ca}{\sqrt{b+3}}\le 3$$

---

We have: $abc\le \frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}=1$

$\Leftrightarrow 2abc\left(\frac{1}{c\sqrt{c+3}}+\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a+3}}+\frac{1}{b\sqrt{b+3}}\right)\le 3$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{c\sqrt{c+3}}+\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a+3}}+\frac{1}{b\sqrt{b+3}}\le \frac{3}{2}$

I can't countinue. Help

Comment: i used to U.C.T (Un Coefficient Technique) but it's wrong

Comment: The last line isn't equivalent to the one before it; it only implies the one before it. (So it is sufficient to prove the last line that you have written, but it is not necessary.) Unfortunately, the last line which you have written is not true, as can be seen by letting $a$ become very small.

Comment: I have a proof, but it's very ugly.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: No problem

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{\sqrt{c+3}}\right)^2\leq\sum_{cyc}ab\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{c+3}.$$
Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}ab\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{c+3}\leq\frac{9}{4}$$ or
$$3v^2\cdot\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}ab(a+3)(b+c)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+3)}\leq\frac{9}{4}$$ or
$$4v^2\sum_{cyc}(a^2b^2+3a^2b+3a^2c+9ab)\leq3\left(abc+27+\sum_{cyc}(3ab+9a)\right)$$ or
$$4v^2(9v^4-6uw^3+27uv^2-9w^3+27v^2)\leq3(w^3+27+9v^2+27u)$$ or
$$w^3(1+12v^2+8uv^2)+27+27u+9v^2\geq12v^6+36uv^4+36v^4.$$
Now, by Schur $w^3\geq4uv^2-3u^3.$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$(4uv^2-3u^3)(1+12v^2+8uv^2)+27+27u+9v^2\geq12v^6+36uv^4+36v^4$$ or
$$27+27u+9v^2+4uv^2+32u^2v^4+12uv^4\geq12v^6+36v^4+3u^3+24u^4v^2+36u^3v^2,$$
which is obvious by Power Mean inequality and AM-GM.

Indeed, this inequality we can get after summing of the following inequalities.

1. $$12uv^4\geq12v^6;$$
2. $$12+12u^2v^4\geq24u^4v^2;$$
3. $$18u^2v^4+18u\geq36u^3v^2;$$
4. $$2+2u^2v^4\geq4v^4$$ 
   and 5. $$13+9u+9v^2+4uv^2\geq32v^4+3u^3.$$
   Done!

Answer (score 1):

Another leaner way.

Some preparation:
From the Power mean inequalities we obtain
$$1 \:=\: \left(\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}3\right)^{\tfrac13}
\:\geqslant\:\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}3\right)^{\tfrac12}
\:\geqslant\:\frac{a+b+c}3\,,$$
hence
$$3\:\geqslant\: a+b+c\,,\text{ and by AGM,}\quad
ab+bc+ca\:\leqslant\: a^2+b^2+c^2\:\leqslant\: 3\,.$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2ab}{\sqrt{c+3}}+
\frac{2bc}{\sqrt{a+3}}+\frac{2ca}{\sqrt{b+3}}
 \: & =\: 2\sum_\text{cyc}\sqrt{ab}\:\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c+3}}\\[2ex]
& \leqslant\: 2\sqrt{\sum_\text{cyc}ab}\:\sqrt{\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{ab}{c+3}}\quad\text{by Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz} \\[2ex]
 & \leqslant\: 2\sqrt{\,3\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{ab}{c+a+b+c}}\quad\text{using the preparations} \\[2ex]
& \leqslant\: 2\sqrt{\,3\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{ab}{4}\left(\frac{1}{c+a}+\frac{1}{b+c}\right)}\quad\text{by }\:\frac1{\text{AM}}\leqslant\frac1{\text{HM}} \\[2ex]
 & =\:\sqrt{\,3\sum_\text{cyc}\left(\frac{ab}{c+a}+\frac{ab}{b+c}\right)} \;=\;\sqrt{\,3\,(a+b+c)}\:\leqslant\:3\,.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm going to edit your lean & convincing solution, which merits (more) upvotes, by adding some explanations + formatting. If you, Michael Rozenberg, are not convinced, then simply do a rollback.